# Matching building footprint edges using frechet distance in geopandas/shapely

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I'm trying through code examples with point data to figure out how to identify matching polygon edges of historical buildings. I have a 19th-century map and almost current OSM data. I'd like to know which polygon edges correspond or, if they are close, calculate a Frechet distance to help understand systematic movements and match all corresponding features.

So far, from other StackOverflow examples and documentation, I've learned to set a spatial index to improve the processing time. Still, I don't see an example that disassembles the polygons and applies the `frechet_distance` operator, but my weak Python skills stumble over the Geopandas dataframe manipulations.

Revising the question after helpful pointers, I'll focus on the significant operation: determining the frechet distance between spatially coincident polygons in the two geodataframes. The code I have now written.

```
# calculate frechet distances of mapOSM with map19thC polygons
matches = mapOSM.applymap(map16thC.frechet_distance(row))
```

returns the error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1cb8165e44ef> in <module>()
      1 # calculate intersections of map2020 buffered polygons with map16thC polygons
----> 2 matches = mapOSM.applymap(map16thC.frechet_distance(row))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'frechet_distance'
```

What is a better way to code this?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! Please read the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) and use formatted code blocks rather than quote blocks. And please check your question's preview before posting.

Comment: also, please see the guide to [ask]. "I'm stuck" isn't a question. Please ask a specific question, showing us what you want to do next and *what's not working*. Include [tracebacks](//realpython.com/python-traceback) and data in a [mre], such that we can reproduce your problem, as formatted code blocks. Make sure you define and describe the various parts of the problem... e.g. you can't join *what* table into *which* dataframe? thanks!

Comment: You are very right. "I'm stuck" isn't a question, nor was it my question. I was raising too broad of a question judging from your response.  From your question to me--thank you--I think I can explain in more detail here. I have two geodataframes. One has polygons from a topographic map of the 19th Century. The other geodataframe contains polygons from a recent OSM map of the same area. Both use the same coordinate system. The goal is to match line segments from the polygons in each data set that correspond to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please edit your question to include the code that shows what you’ve tried and what’s not working. This guide gives helpful perspective: https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: The shapely frechet_distance should be adequate for those computations. I have attempted to use pandas.DataFrame.apply and pandas.DataFrame.applymap, but neither work.

Comment: this is getting closer! please always include the *full traceback*. not just the last line. and what makes you think that geopandas should have a method called `frechet_distance`? where are you getting the idea that that method should exist? you reference "stack overflow examples and documentation". can you be specific?

Comment: I've added the full traceback. Could you explain how is knowing that line 5487 of generic.py is helpful? I know brevity is valuable, why it would be a curse here is important for me to understand.

Comment: I don't see the full traceback. read the guide to [ask], [mre], and read all the way through this explanation of [python tracebacks](//realpython.com/python-traceback) I already sent you.

Comment: Also, the frechet_distance method would seem to be in geopandas, but I only found it in shapely. The library issue is important but the geopandas documentation states, "Geometric operations are performed by shapely." (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html). At my level of understanding, it means all geometry functions shapely library are in geopandas. But your point suggests about my statement suggests otherwise. How do you know if a geometry function in shapely isn't available in geopandas would be another question for you.

Comment: Specific examples for use of frechet_distance are few. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309517/matching-building-footprint-edges-using-frechet-distance-in-geopandas-shapely

Comment: that's a link to this question

Comment: *"it means all geometry functions shapely library are in geopandas"* that's not the case at all. in order to call `GeoDataFrame.method`, method needs to be actually implemented in geopands. See the [Geopandas API](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference.html) - it has to be here (or in the pandas documentation, as GeoDataFrame inherrits from pandas.DataFrame) in order for you to call it. However - I also don't see it anywhere in the shapely docs. If you can show me the actual documentation pointing to where `frechet_distance` exists then I can help you, but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation in shapely: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measurement.html?highlight=frechet#shapely.measurement.frechet_distance

Comment: Ok thanks. This is a pre-release version of shapely. So you’ll need to make sure you’re using shapely v2.0-a.1 in order to use this function, and then you’d need to work with the geometries manually in shapely - you can’t just call this on a geodataframe. I think it might be easier to just find an implementation somewhere and implement it yourself. But no matter what I’d try to make this work in a small test dataframe first without the groupby and then try to get the groupby apply working. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll take that approach now. I'll post something when I have that sussed out.